# Closing an FOSUserBundle Login from an iFrame Magnific popup?

Tags: javascript, jquery, symfony, fosuserbundle, magnific-popup

I'm trying to create a popup for an fosuserbundle login in Symfony2. I decided (smartly or not?) to use [Magnific-Popup](https://github.com/dimsemenov/Magnific-Popup). It looks like I have 2 real options: iFrame or Ajax. iFrame seems to work, I get my login form and authenticate inside the Magnific popup with no Problem.

HTML

```
<a class="popup-login" href="{{ path('my_login_path') }}">Login</a><br>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.popup-login').magnificPopup({
    disableOn: 700,
    type: 'iframe',
    mainClass: 'mfp-fade',
    removalDelay: 160,
    preloader: false,
    fixedContentPos: false
});
});
```

I'd like to use the classic FOSUserBundle and Symfony2 behaviour for the redirect on login to a rendered template (failure would leave me on the same template). That template looks something like this: "Thanks for logging in blah, blah, blah **CLOSE LINK**"... And there's my problem. I have no idea how to create the link that closes my Magnific popup in that rendered page. The "X" closes the iFrame just fine.

I see the api call to close the frame and I assume my answer lies there:

```
this.close()
```

But have no idea how it should be implemented.

I'm wondering if I've taken the wrong path here. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks.